# Add event in vue Bootstrap Datatables

Tags: vue.js, datatable

I'm starting now with vue and found the following difficulty in the tables:

I'm using Vue Bootstrap Datatables https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/tables/datatables/ with the following code

```
  <mdb-datatable
     :data="'http://localhost/category/list_category'"
     striped
     bordered
     responsive
     lengthChange = "false"
     :tfoot="false"
     arrows
     reactive
     :time="3000"
   />
```

The **list_category** method returns a valid json to populate the table. Everything works perfectly.

[image]

As you can see I work with two columns, one of them is the name and the other is deletion and editing actions. The code that generates the rows array is as follows:

> I'm using codeigniter here

```
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("mycategory");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $ar = array();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $ar[] = array(
                    'name' => $row->name,
                    'acciones' => "
                        <a @click.prevent='delete' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Borrar'><i class='dripicons-trash text-danger'></i></a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        <a @click.prevent='edit' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Editar' ><i class=' dripicons-document-edit text-success'></i></a>"
                );
            }
            return $ar;
        }
```

i'm adding click events in the tags that are my actions in the table, the problem is that after the table is rendered with the data, the click event is not 'seen' by the vue. Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible in any way?

Comment: I've run into similar problems where the elements to be targeted at the time Vue sets up event listeners, so they don't fire when you want. Does `mdb-datatable` (or another part of your code) have an event that fires when the table is built? You could hook into that event and set up event listeners then, after all the elements are created.

Comment: Good idea @ebbishop... I think it can work... I'll test it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this attr in mdb-datatable tag

`:translations="{
      countLabel: 'row selected',
      add: 'Add',
      edit: 'Edit',
      delete: 'Delete',
      selectLabel: 'Show entries',
      searchLabel: 'Search',
      prev: 'Previous',
      next: 'Next',
      addFormLabel: 'Add new form',
      addFormBtn: 'Add form',
      editFormLabel: 'Edit form',
      editFormBtn: 'Edit form',
      deleteFormLabel: 'Delete',
      deleteFormText: 'Are you sure to delete selected row?',
      deleteFormYes: 'Yes',
      deleteFormNo: 'No'
    }"`

Comment: I added the attribute but nothing happens :( could you explain what it does?